# How to assign our own function to MatDialog in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on implementing Popup/Dialog using [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). There is build in function  `openDialog()` to open dialog box, I want to change it to my `function`

This is my `DashboardComponent`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MymodalComponent } from '../modals/mymodal/mymodal.component';   

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

openDialog(): void {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LastseenDevicesComponent, {
    width: '80%',
    height:'80%',
    panelClass: 'my-dialog',
    disableClose: true ,
  data: { name: "this.name", animal: "this.city" }
});
```

Html file of `DashboardComponent`

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Where do you stay?</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name">
    </mat-form-field>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick city or food</button>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="city">
    You chose: <i>{{city}}</i>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="food_from_modal">
    I love {{food_from_modal}}
  </li>
</ol>
```

This is dialog component `LastseenDevicesComponent`

```
<div md-dialog-content>
     <button class="close" mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    
    <p>What's your favorite city?</p>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Favorite City</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.city">
    </mat-form-field>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button id="matbuttonClose" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
  </div>
</html>
```

**This is how I want to make it instead of `openDialog(): void` I want to replace it with my code in `DashboardComponent`**

```
//This getting called when I click on my chart bar
function lastSeenDevice() {

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LastseenDevicesComponent, {
    width: '80%',
    height:'80%',
    panelClass: 'my-dialog',
    disableClose: true ,
  data: { name: this.name, animal: this.city }
});
```

If I do this getting error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at Chart.lastSeenDevice (dashboard.component.ts:509)
at Chart.handleEvent (Chart.js:10213)
at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:10150)
at listener (Chart.js:10083)
at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies.<computed> (Chart.js:7813)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
```

Comment: To be clear, instead of calling the openDialog() function, you want it to call lastSeenDevice correct?

Comment: @Raven - Yes, correct.

Comment: Did you inject a MatDialog to your DashboardComponent's constructor?

Comment: @John - Yes, Please check my first code snippet.  `constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) ` . If I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because of losing of context (`this` is null in your function). For fix it you should set context manually, with `bind` for example (but in this case you can override context only once):

```
ngOnInit() {
  lastSeenDevice = lastSeenDevice.bind(this);
}
```

or declare your function with arrow function inside of your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  window.lastSeenDevice = () => { this.dialog.open(...) }
}
```

For fix typing error with second option you can manually set type of window to any: `(<any>window).lastSeenDevice`

Also I you need to clear global function in `ngOnDestroy` for avoid memory leaks.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 (<any>window).lastSeenDevice = null;
}
```

Comment: Even I have to use `this` in your first part of code without this not working. Thank you for update..

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this error is seen:

```
Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

Is that the "this" in this.dialog.open inside your lastSeenDevice() function refers to a different context than that of the class.

So to fix this:
Inside your dashboard component make sure you have the lastSeenDevice() function, and remove the "function" keyword to make it a class method and thus will refer "this" as context of the Dashboard class.

So from:

```
function lastSeenDevice() { ... your code here . . .}
```

to:

```
lastSeenDevice() { ... your code here ... }
```

Also make sure that on:

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">
```

You change it to:

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="lastSeenDevice()">
```

Comment: I do not have button in html file rather I have `<canvas id="cv1" ></canvas>` for I have function in typescript file.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya alright. In that case you might want to change context of your lastSeenDevice function.

At the top of your Dashboard component file, add this:
declare var window: any;

Comment: Then on your ngOnInit() add this:
window.lastSeenDevice = window.lastSeenDevice.bind(this);